# How to add a x-axis line to a figure? (matlab)

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, horizontal-line

I want to add a x-axis line at 0 to a Matlab figure so that I can compare my data to see if it is positive or negative when saving the figures to a jpg.  What is the best way to do this?  I know you can use `line()` but it just seems cumbersome because you need to specify the x and the y ranges.  Is there an easier way?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/17798093/7328782 for a similar question about vertical lines.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to draw horizontal and vertical lines in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28334660/how-to-draw-horizontal-and-vertical-lines-in-matlab)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't believe there is a built-in way that is more convenient. I use `hline()` and `vline()` from FileExchange, which work like a charm:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/1039

Answer (score 32):

There exist an undocumented function `graph2d.constantline`:

```
plot(-2:5, (-2:5).^2-1)

%# vertical line
hx = graph2d.constantline(0, 'LineStyle',':', 'Color',[.7 .7 .7]);
changedependvar(hx,'x');

%# horizontal line
hy = graph2d.constantline(0, 'Color',[.7 .7 .7]);
changedependvar(hy,'y');
```

[image: screenshot]

The nice thing is that it internally implements a listener for the axes limits (handles change like pan, zoom, etc..). So the lines would appear to extend to infinity.

Comment: Looks like my version of Matlab 7.0.1 R14 SP1 gives me a segmentation violation when I run your code and I don't get the x-axis line. :(

Comment: why the downvote, your version of [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB#Release_history) is pretty old, and as it turns out doesn't run the above solution.. Plus as I mentioned, this is an undocumented feature

Comment: sorry, i didn't think it would do so. i tried to undo the upvote, but it caused the downvote instead.  not very intuitive.. =/ now i can't do anything since the ans is locked until the post is edited and i don't have editing privileges.

Comment: Very nice solution! Exactly what i've been searching for a long time!

Comment: update: unfortunately the function was removed in R2014b (which introduced the new HG2 graphics system).

Answer (score 7):

You could get this x range directly after the figure has been created. It goes a little something like this:

```
x=-2:5;
y=x.^2-1;

figure()
plot(x,y);

xlim = get(gca,'xlim');  %Get x range 
hold on
plot([xlim(1) xlim(2)],[0 0],'k')
```

[image]

Note that if you do any manual zooming out in the figure, the line might have to be redrawn to go over the entire new x range.

Answer (score 6):

A `vline` and `hline` command like in GNU R would be great, but I could not find a shorter solution than

```
plot(1:10,sin(1:10));
line(xlim,[0 0],'Color','r')
```

Comment: This is a very elegant method!

Answer (score 1):

1. Draw your data by `plot()` command or `stem()`. A figure window will open.
2. Then on the figure window, click on the [insert] command from the
        menu bar, a drop-down menu will appear.
3. From this menu click on the [line] command, now the shape of the
        cursor will change into a plus sign.
4. Now you can draw a line anywhere you want, either horizontal or
        vertical or slanted.
5. You can change the properties of line by right clicking on the
        line, a menu will appear from which you can choose your desires
        properties.
6. If you want to have some ticks on the line then you can use add 
        text option, and place text where ever you want.
7. If you would like to have a code for your figure, click on [file]
        menu and then click on [generatecode] option, a new text editor
        window will open, you can save this code for further use. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Since MATLAB R2018b there is [`yline`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/yline.html) for this purpose:

```
 yline(0)
```

draws a horizontal line at `y==0`.