# Vertical refline in matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot

How do I draw a vertical refline in matlab? e.g. I want to plot a line of x=5. Obviously using inf does not help at all. Can anyone give some advice?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/8086943/7328782 for a similar question regarding horizontal lines.

Comment: Easy way using `stem` in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55355699/8239061) for those with releases prior to `xline` 's release in R2018b.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to draw horizontal and vertical lines in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28334660/how-to-draw-horizontal-and-vertical-lines-in-matlab)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create a vector with many identical values for x. Something like this:

```
x = 5*ones(1,100);
y = 1:100;
plot(x,y)
```

or use the line function:

```
line([5,5],[0,10])
```

To automatically detect the range of line, use ylim:

```
plot(1:10)

line([5,5],ylim)
```

Comment: I want it to automatically determine the endpoints of the line instead of me specifying the two points...

Comment: Note! `ylim` is a matlab function in and of itself that does exactly what you have called it to do - there is no need to override the builtin using the line `ylim = get(gca,'ylim')`

Comment: oops! Correction made. Thanks.

Comment: You can also use `plot` itself `plot([5 5], ylim)`. That makes it easier to combine it with other plot commands.

Answer (score 3):

Since MATLAB R2018b there is [`xline`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xline.html) for this purpose:

```
 xline(0)
```

draws a vertical line at `x==0`.

Answer (score 1):

There is an excellent answer over on https://stackoverflow.com/a/8108766/1194420 repeated below for convenience. (Please go there an up vote the original answer) ---

There exist an undocumented function graph2d.constantline:

```
plot(-2:5, (-2:5).^2-1)
%# vertical line
hx = graph2d.constantline(0, 'LineStyle',':', 'Color',[.7 .7 .7]);
changedependvar(hx,'x');
%# horizontal line
hy = graph2d.constantline(0, 'Color',[.7 .7 .7]);
changedependvar(hy,'y');
```

Answer (score 1):

The function [`refline`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/refline.html) lets you specify gradient and intercept.

Answer (score 1):

You can use refline and then edit the XData and YData properties to create a vertical line.