# How do I plot a single vertical line in matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot

```
theta = linspace(0,2*pi,200); y = theta;x = 10;plot(x,y,'o');
```

When i write this i get the points but when i replace plot(x,y,'o') with plot(x,y) I should get a vertical line at x=4 but the graph comes empty..

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Please add more details of the issue that you are facing.

Comment: What about `plot([xStart xEnd], [yStart yEnd])`, if you just need a line between two points?

Comment: In R2018b onward, there's the function [`xline`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xline.html) for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vertical refline in matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17798093/vertical-refline-in-matlab)

Comment: (CASE 1)When I write the following code I get a graph with 10 points (in the y=x direction)
The Code is 
***  x = linspace(0,10,10);
y = x ;
plot (x,y,'o');   ***
(CASE 2)Now If I write only plot(x,y) in the above code instead of plot(x,y,'o') I get y=x line which is expected  BUT Now in the following case 
(CASE 3)When I write the following code 
***a= linspace (0,2*pi,20);
y = a;
x = 10;
plot(x,y,'o'); ***
The result is I get 20 points (Same as case 1)
Now if I replace plot(x,y,'o') to plot (x,y) in the above code (in Case 3)
I should get a line(Same as case 2)But I dont get it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to draw horizontal and vertical lines in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28334660/how-to-draw-horizontal-and-vertical-lines-in-matlab)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `stem`

```
x = 10;
y = 200;
stem(x,y,'Marker','none');
```

[image: stem plot]

Comment: Clever. And works for those with versions before `xline` released.  (+1)

Answer (score 1):

From this answer: https://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/2031-adding-vertical-line-to-plot

```
fig=figure; 
hax=axes; 
x=0:0.1:10; 
hold on 
plot(x,sin(x)) 
SP=1; %your point goes here 
line([SP SP],get(hax,'YLim'),'Color',[1 0 0])
```