# How to draw horizontal and vertical lines in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot, horizontal-line

I am currently trying to plot a simple vertical and horizontal lines in MATLAB.

For instance, I would like to plot the line y=245. How would I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MATLAB's plotting works on a point-by-point basis from the vectors you give.  So to create a horizontal line, you need to varying `x` while keeping `y` constant and vice-versa for vertical lines:

```
xh = [0,10];
yh = [245,245]; % constant

xv = [5,5]; % constant
yv = [0,245*2];

plot(xh,yh,xv,yv);
```

Answer (score 1):

2 simple ways:

```
plot(0:0.001:1, 25);

line('XData', [0 1], 'YData', [25 25]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since MATLAB R2018b you can use the functions [xline](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xline.html) and [yline](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/yline.html):

```
>> yline(245);
```