# MATLAB- adding a line to plot (scatter)

Tags: matlab, plot, scatter-plot, horizontal-line

I am making a "movie" where the dots should move each X time

Here is the code (not copy paste so dont fix typos)

```
loop:
scatter(x,y,[],colors)
axies (a b c d)
pause(0.01);
end loop;
```

This is working great, but how can i add a LINE for the X axise (1:140)

At height 150?

I tired hold on but it just make a mess... or what is the command to clean grough when its in hold on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could this work for you?

```
N = 1000;
X = 1:N;
M = 160;
Y = randi(M, N);

figure
for i = 1:N
    x = X(i);
    y = Y(i);
    scatter(x,y,[])
    hold on
    line([1 N], [150 150])
    hold off
    axis([1 N 0 200])
    pause(0.01);
end
```

Comment: The post-2018b release version of this would replace `line(...)` with `yline(height)` where `height = 150`.  More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28334660/how-to-draw-horizontal-and-vertical-lines-in-matlab).