# Histogram with a mean line in same spot

Tags: matlab, plot, histogram

I'm using Matlab and have created a histogram and want a vertical line to indicate the mean. So far my code is

```
N=100;
mydata=rand(N,1);
mymean=mean(mydata);
histogram(mydata);
figure(1)
hold on
line(mymean,N,'r')
```

I expect to find a red line crossing the x-axis at the mean value, but there is no line plotted. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want your line to go from the point `p1=[mymean 0]` to the point `p2=[mymean N]`. Just tell that to the `line` function. Right now you are drawing a line that only goes to a point, so it is that, a point.

```
line([mymean mymean],[0 N],'r')
```

But I see no reason to use `line` as it is just a low level function of `plot`, so just do

```
plot([mymean mymean],[0 N],'r')
```

Comment: Thanks that works except for 'r'. Is there a way to change the width or color of the line?

Answer (score 0):

Starting in the 2018b version, [`xline()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xline.html) draws a vertical line.

```
N = 100;
mydata = rand(N,1);
mymean = mean(mydata);
h = histogram(mydata);
h2 = xline(mymean,'r-','LineWidth',1.5);    % Requires MATLAB R2018b or later
```

Other LineStyles are available: `'-'`, `'--'`, `':'`, `'-.'`.

```
h2.LineStyle = '--';
```

Color is also easily changed.

For more info, see [How to draw horizontal and vertical lines in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28334660/8239061), especially [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54746630/8239061).

[image: Example output figure with red vertical line at mymean.]