# Plotting Additional Line w/o adjusting Plot Window around Original Data in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, axis, scatter-plot, horizontal-line

I have a scatterplot of data in Matlab, along with a horizontal linegraph which divides two sub groups of this data - all on the same plot. I have plotted these two entities separately using the `hold on` command.

Ideally, I want the plot window to automatically adjust to just the scatterplot data, and would prefer the horizontal line I plotted to simply extend off the screen in all cases. Is there a simple way to do this?

At the moment when I change the limits of the horizontal line, the graph window shifts to accommodate these points, skewing the view of the scatterplot data I'm actually interested in.

Example:

```
% central line segment
boundary_line = plot(csv_results.data(:,9),csv_results.data(:,10));

% negative extension of line segment off screen
line_negext = plot([-10,csv_results.data(1,9)],[csv_results.data(1,10),csv_results.data(1,10)]);

% positive extension of line segment off screen
line_posext = plot([10,csv_results.data(6,9)],[csv_results.data(6,10),csv_results.data(6,10)]);

% scatterplot data of interest
scatt_data = plot(csv_results.data(:,3),csv_results.data(:,4));
```

UPDATE: My problem is that, as seen in my code above, I need to plot two line segments at different y values that continue to positive and negative infinity, which link up to an existing plot in the middle. If I use `yline` I can simply draw one horizontal line - if I use `xlim` I risk cropping out data for subsequent runs..

Comment: Have you tried [`xlim()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlim.html)?  Could you use `xlim([xL xR])` to keep the plot only showing the x-axis from `xL` to `xR`?

Comment: Are you using [`yline()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/yline.html) or manually plotting the horizontal line?

Comment: Thank you for the tips! I am currently plotting the horizontal line manually...

Comment: Thanks for the code update. What version of MATLAB are you using?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am using 2018b - my problem is that, as seen in my code above, I need to plot two line segments at different y values that continue to positive and negative infinity, which link up to an existing plot in the middle. If I use `yline` I can simply draw one horizontal line - if I use `xlim` I risk cropping out data for subsequent runs..

Comment: My current idea is to determine the max and min of the data for every run, and use these values as the limits using `xlim`

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Since we don't have your data, this is difficult to replicate.  Similar to my post below, could you [edit] your post to have a [mcve] (data) to illustrate the difficulty?  I imagine this is quite solvable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Image showing horizontal line]

If you want to adjust the axis to more restrictive portion (reduce), then [`xlim()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlim.html) and [`ylim()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ylim.html) get the job done. Horizontal lines drawn by [`yline()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/yline.html) will persist, as will vertical lines drawn by [`xline()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xline.html). Note that `xline()` and `yline()` should work for releases including R2018b and later.

```
% MATLAB R2019a
% Sample Data
n = 10;
X1 = 5*rand(n,1);
Y1 = 5*rand(n,1);
X2 = 5 + 5*rand(n,1);
Y2 = 5 + 5*rand(n,1);

figure, hold on
yline(5) 
scatter(X1,Y1,'bo')
scatter(X2,Y2,'rd')
scatter(X1,Y2,'ks')
xlim([0 5])
```

Notice that by calling `xlim()` for a larger x-axis range also expands the horizontal line.

```
xlim([-1,12])
```

---

If you plot new data after `xlim()` outside the range, the plot won't automatically adjust.  However, if you do so before calling `xlim()`, then the horizontal line will expand.  Try the example below.

```
figure, hold on
yline(5) 
scatter(X1,Y1,'bo')
scatter(X2,Y2,'rd')
scatter(X1,Y2,'ks')
```

Then immediately execute

```
scatter(100*rand(n,1),Y1)
```

and see that the horizontal line has expanded to cover the new, much longer x-axis. 
[image: Image showing expanded horizontal line]

---

After posting this answer, I found:  [How to draw horizontal and vertical lines in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28334660/8239061)